# How to find root cuase of Uncaught Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:

Tags: c#, asp.net

`Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException:` Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

I am getting this error when I am clicking on the button for the second time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an IndexOutOfRangeException / ArgumentOutOfRangeException and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20940979/what-is-an-indexoutofrangeexception-argumentoutofrangeexception-and-how-do-i-f)

Answer (score 0):

Commented Update Panel under ASPX, and web page has shown actual error on the screen and resolved it.

Issue is under SelectedIndex Changed Event and Not able to find the Item of [0].